# Свойство которое возвращает ссылку на объект класса

Tags: c#, ооп

Нужно чтобы свойство после некоторых манипуляций вернуло ссылку на объект с наибольшей датой, вот как я пытался сделать но выдает ошибку в этом месте

```
 Auto x = auto[nomax];
 ref Auto xRef = ref x;
 return ref xRef;
```

Возможно я не понял/не нашел, как правильно присваивать/обращаться.
Весь код ниже

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;

namespace ddddddddddd
{
    class Program
    {
    class  Auto{
            public DateTime autoDate;
            public Auto()
            {
                this.autoDate = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }


        class Fares :Auto { 
        public static Auto[] auto;
        public static int Fares_i = 0;
        
           Fares(Auto obj)
        {
              
                auto[Fares_i] = obj;
                Fares_i++;
            }
              
           
           
            public static ref Auto[] last_auto
            {
                get
                {
                    DateTime[] list = new DateTime[Fares_i];
                    DateTime max = list[0];
                    int nomax = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < Fares_i; i++)
                    {
                        list[i] = auto[i].autoDate;
                        if (list[i] > max)
                        {
                            max = list[i];
                            nomax = i;
                        }
                    }

                 
                    Auto x = auto[nomax];
                    ref Auto xRef = ref x;
                    return ref xRef;
                }
            }   
        }
```

Comment: `но выдает ошибку в этом месте` текст ошибки?

Comment: Класс или массив - ссылочный тип, его не нужно рефать. Технически переменная типа класс - это и есть ссылка. Рефать можно структуру или базовые типы. То есть просто `return x;`.

Comment: @aepot тип `Auto x` не соответсвует `Auto[] last_auto`

Comment: @tym32167 Ну да, хочет объект с наибольшей датой, а возвращаемый тип - массив. Но это уже другая история, я только про рефы отписался. Там что-то типа `OrderBy(...).Last()` поможет, ну и исправить тип свойства.

Comment: @aepot да и массив автору не нужен дополнительный, по сути всю имплементацию свойства ему можно выкинуть. OrderBy не обязательно, есть же Max, который по идее быстрее, чем OrderBy работать должен.